# Syntax error on mysql in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, windows

this is my query which i generate from c#

```
Select * from contac 
where ((LCASE(first_name) = '' and LCASE(sur_name) = 'bn d. o’connor & co' ) 
or 
(LCASE(first_name) = 'bn d. o’connor & co' and LCASE(sur_name) = '' )) 
and 
Medicom_GP_KEY is null
```

but if i execute and fill Data table means it shows error like

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'connor & co' ) or (LCASE(first_name) = 'bn d. o'connor & co' and LCASE(sur_' at line 1

i do not know where the error is occurs.

Comment: use prepared Statement. It prevents for SQL injection and escapes Special character

Comment: The error message tells you exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: `’` isn't this a single quote too? you need to escape that

Comment: In CP1252 the apostrophe `’` has same code as single quote `'`. Probably this is the cause of syntax error, it should be escaped or use parameterized query with prepared statements.

Comment: ya, but i actually use  `dr["GP FirstName"].ToString().ToLower().Replace("'", @"\'")` to escape

Answer (score 0):

You're escaping the apostrophe on your data reader not on your initial SQL command. Your command should look like:

```
Select * from contac 
where ((LCASE(first_name) = '' and LCASE(sur_name) = 'bn d. o''connor & co' ) 
or 
(LCASE(first_name) = 'bn d. o''connor & co' and LCASE(sur_name) = '' )) 
and 
Medicom_GP_KEY is null
```

Double your single quotes to escape them.